# How to natural sort string with multiple numbers in it

Tags: python

How to do human sorting on below list, I want to sort based on last numbers e.g 45-50, 35-40 etc

```
list_list= ['N1-1TWS-AD03-____-001N-__45-50',
     'N1-1TWS-AD01-____-001N-__50-54',
     'N1-1TWS-AD01-____-001N-__54-58',
     'N1-1TWS-AD01-____-001N-__58-61',
     'N1-1TWS-AD01-____-001N-__61-65',
     'N1-2TWS-AD01-____-001S-__25-28',
     'N1-2TWS-AD01-____-001S-__25-28',
     'N1-3TWS-AD01-____-001S-__28-31',
     'N1-4TWS-AD01-____-001S-__28-31',
     'N1-3TWS-AD01-____-001S-__31-35',
     'N1-3TWS-AD01-____-001S-__31-35',
     'N1-3TWS-AD01-____-001S-__35-40',
     'N1-3TWS-AD01-____-001S-__35-40',
     'N1-3TWS-AD01-____-001S-__40-43',
     'N1-3TWS-AD01-____-001S-__40-43',
     'N1-3TWS-AD01-____-001S-__43-47']
```

I tried sort and sorted but it wasn't giving the result I wanted.
I want to sort like

```
['N1-2TWS-AD01-____-001S-__25-28',
'N1-2TWS-AD01-____-001S-__25-28',
'N1-3TWS-AD01-____-001S-__28-31',
'N1-4TWS-AD01-____-001S-__28-31',
 ...and so on...
'N1-1TWS-AD01-____-001N-__61-65']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Comment: @Ch3steR not quite, his problem is simple without multiple numbers in a single string

Comment: What do you mean by human sorting? Which strings do you want to come first and which next?

Comment: @user13044086 go google natural sorting aka human sorting

Comment: Judging from the way you've provided your ideal sorted result is it only the last two double digits you want to sort by?

Comment: I've put a solution in the answers assuming that's what you mean. Let me know if you mean otherwise!

Comment: @Swazy Is there a way to do it for df column ? I want columns to move as the key column

Comment: Hey @EegiiEnkhtaivan. I'm afraid I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you mean there is another part of the string you would like to sort by as well?

Comment: @Swazy Hi, Swazy. I mean is it possible to perform below in DF column ?

Comment: Oh you mean sort items in a pandas DataFrame column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
z = sorted(list_list, key=lambda s: (s[-5:-3], s[-2:]))
```

Comment: Probably `z = sorted(list_list, key=lambda s: s[:-5])` will be enough for the provided data

Comment: Yeah agreed. Thought it might be nice to be explicit about how you could extract specific integers from the string to sort by. Maybe more complicated than necessary though :)